# Borrar textbox wpf MVVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm

estoy tratando de que despues de insertar un dato en la base de datos se borre el texto del textbox. Me lo hace todo correcto menos el borrado del textbox.

```html
        <TextBlock Text="Blog" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,0,10,0" ></TextBlock>
        <TextBox Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,0,0,20" Width="150" Height="30" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Blog.Nombre, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"></TextBox>
        <Button Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  Width="auto" Command="{Binding CrearBlogCommand}"/>
```

```html
    public class CrearBlogViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        private RelayCommand crearBlogCommand;
        public ICommand CrearBlogCommand
        {
            get
            {
                if(crearBlogCommand == null)
                {
                    this.crearBlogCommand = new RelayCommand(param => CrearBlog(), param => true);
                }
                return crearBlogCommand;
            }         
        }

        private Blog blog;

        public Blog Blog
        {
            get
            {
                if(this.blog == null)
                {
                    this.blog = new Blog();
                }
                return blog;
            }
            set
            {
                
                base.OnPropertyChanged("Blog");
            }
        }

        private void CrearBlog()
        {
            var nuevoBlog = new DABlog();

            try
            {
                nuevoBlog.CrearBLog(new Blog() { Nombre = this.Blog.Nombre });
                MessageBox.Show("Blog creado correctamente");
                this.Blog.Nombre = string.Empty;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                MessageBox.Show("Se a producido un error");
            }            
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aunque ya resolviste tu problema, deja te comento que podrías hacer una mejor implementación del patrón MVVM.

No deberías estar llamando a PropertyChanged, imagínate si luego tienes mas propiedades en el mismo caso?

Se me ocurre que una mejor solución es que en tu clase Blog también implementes INotifyPropertyChanged, de esa forma solo escribes:

```
this.Blog.Nombre = string.Empty.
```

Y eso debería actualizar la vista.

Si no quieres implementar INPC en Blog, la solución adecuada, o al menos como indica el patrón, es crear un  proxy de las propiedades del modelo que quieras bindear.

Ejemplo:

```
private Blog Blog { get; set; }


public string Nombre
{
    get { return Blog.Nombre; }
    set 
    {
        Blog.Nombre = value;
        base.OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Nombre));
    }
}
```

Y en vez de

```
Text="{Binding Blog.Nombre
```

Haces:

```
Text="{Binding Nombre
```

De esta forma no solo estás siguiendo el patrón sino que no estás dando trabajo al modelo de algo que es responsabilidad del ViewModel. Y también te evita problemas en el futuro.

Por último, un par de comentarios mas, no hagas llamadas a MessageBox.Show o cualquier cosa relacionada con la vista en el viewmodel, la idea de MVVM es que el ViewModel no conozca nada de la vista, así estás haciendo referencia a WPF en el VM.

El otro comentario es que evites totalmente esto:

```
base.OnPropertyChanged("Blog");
```

Eso puede introducir bugs, ¿que tal si escribes mal el nombre de la propiedad? o ¿que tal si refactorizas el nombre de la propiedad y se te olvida cambiar la cadena que le pasas al método "OnPropertyChanged?

Si no quieres hacer cambios en tu implementación del MVVM utiliza al menos nameof, de esa forma al menos el compilador te advierte de errores.

Lo ideal es, si estás usando .net 4.5, utilizar el atributo CallerMemberName en el metodo OnPropertyChanged:

```
public sub OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
{
    // el código seguiría igual
}
```

De esta forma, en vez de :

```
base.OnPropertyChanged("Nombre");
```

Lo usas así:

```
base.OnPropertyChamged();
```

El compilador se encargará de poner el nombre de la propiedad y ya no hay problema si en el futuro cambias el nombre de la propiedad.

Espero te ayude un poco mi respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

Me contesto a mi mismo por si a alguien le surge la misma pregunta.

```
OnPropertyChanged(Blog.Nombre = string.Empty);
```

Comment: Hola Alejandro. Me alegra que lo solucionaras. Sin embargo, has de explicar mejor la respuesta. Mira [answer] para mejorarla. Un saludo